# Qt Virtual Keyboard touch screen device

Tags: qt, keyboard, qml, virtual

I am getting some weird behaviour from the Qt Virtual Keyboard on QML. I have a TextInput which has focus, but it will not receive the keystrokes until I do an actual click (using a real mouse, not touch) somewhere on the screen. I am also getting "input method not set" in the log. The system is running Ubuntu 20.04. Anybody came across something like this. Any hints/help would be appreciated.

Would also like to mention that the touch screen works for all the other screen navigation

Please see my code below:

```
Rectangle {
        id: passwordFieldId
        anchors.top: passwordPromptId.bottom
        anchors.topMargin: 30
        anchors.horizontalCenter: userPasswordBackgroundId.horizontalCenter
        color: HLGStyles.white
        border.color: HLGStyles.black
        border.width: 1
        width: 350
        height: 40

        TextInput {
            id: passwordInputFieldId
            echoMode: TextInput.Password
            anchors.fill: parent
            font {family: liberationSansRegular.name; pointSize: HLGStyles.mediumFont}
            color: HLGStyles.black
            visible: passwordVirtualKeyboardId.visible
            onVisibleChanged: if(visible) passwordInputFieldId.forceActiveFocus()
            onActiveFocusChanged: {
                if(activeFocus) {
                    Qt.inputMethod.update(Qt.ImQueryInput)
                }
            }
            focus: passwordVirtualKeyboardId.visible
            padding: 2
            verticalAlignment: TextInput.AlignVCenter
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            Keys.onReturnPressed: viewModel.onEnterPressed(passwordInputFieldId.text)
        }
    }

    InputPanel {
        id: passwordVirtualKeyboardId
        visible: (guiManager.currentScreenDisplayed === Screens.SoftwareUpdate) && (viewModel.currentScreen === viewModel.userPasswordScreenName) ? true : false
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        width: parent.width * 0.95
        height: parent.height * 0.5
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 140
    }
```